# Strange behavior of the std::map with atypical comparator

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

Lets consider following code snippet:

```
class A 
{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
    A(int ix, int iy) : x(ix), y(iy) {}
    bool operator < (const A& a) const
    { return (x < a.x) || (y < a.y); } 
};


int main()
{
    std::map<A,int> amap;
    amap[A(0,1)] = 4;
    amap[A(1,0)] = 5;
    for(auto &x: amap)
        std::cout<<x.second<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<amap[A(0,1)]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<amap[A(1,0)]<<std::endl;
}
```

Output is `5 4 4 0`

- I expected that only the first element `A(0,1)` will be inserted, but both elements were added. Why?
- First element `A(0,1)` has been found, but second search of the element `A(1,0)` didn't find it. Why?

Can someone explain in details what is happening in this case in the `std::map`?

Comment: Your comparison operator does not implement a strict weak ordering. That is a requirement, so your map is broken.

Comment: @ juanchopanza, I understand, but... why exactly this behaviour?

Comment: `std::map` needs this for its internal structure. It is a binary search tree.

Comment: @gorill - Using Visual Studio, you would have been greeted with an assertion using the debugging libraries, thus no "behaviour" would be seen.  VS does the trick of calling your comparitor twice, once with the arguments "a, b", then the comparitor with "b, a".  If you return `true` for both, the assert is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A a(0, 1), b(1, 0);
```

Then `a < b && b < a`. As you can see, your ordering is not assymetric. Neither is it irreflexive as `a < a`.
All those are requirements for a strict weak ordering, an ordering every `map` needs. Without it, your results can quickly get unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

For all elements that you insert into the map, if `a < b` is true then `b < a` must be false. Your comparison operator does not do this.

A `map` uses a tree structure, and navigating the tree is done with the comparison operator. If the comparison operator generates inconsistent results then the navigation gets lost.